# Get attribute of an instance from another file python

Tags: python

I have three files; File 1 contains a class that has an attribute I want to obtain.

File 2 contains the main class where all large instances are created.

File 3 contains another class that must read information from File 1's class to determine the information it send File1's instance.

File1;

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.listAttribute = [[],[],[]] #attribute i want to obtain in File 3
```

File 2;

```
import File1
import File3

def main():
    newFoo = File1.Foo()
    newBar = File3.Bar() 

    print(newFoo.listAttribute)
    print(newBar.doSomething())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

File 3;

```
import File2

class Bar(object):
    def doSomething(self):
        print(File2.newFoo.listAttribute)
```

I feel like the calling main part isn't the right thing to do. But calling the instance outside of a function doesn't work either. I thought about calling the instance in another location, just unsure where to call the instance.

Comment: File 2 imports file 3, and file 3 imports file 2.  You can't do that.

Comment: Also, `newFoo` is not an importable item in file 2, because it's a local variable inside `main()`.  If it were declared at the module level, at the outermost scope, then it would be importable.

Comment: Do i need to restructure? If i cant import file2 from file3 and reversed then I struggle to see how this works... Where should i be instantiating my classes then?

Comment: define `def doSomething(self, instance): print(instance.listAttribute)` and in File2 use `print(newBar.doSomething(newFoo))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better send instance as argument

```
def doSomething(self, instance): 
    print(instance.listAttribute)
```

and then in `File2` use

```
print(newBar.doSomething(newFoo))
```

This way you don't have to import `File2` in `File3` - and you don't have problem with imports.

And everybody who will read `File2` will see that `newBar` uses `newFoo` - so this information will not be hidden in `File3`.

Comment: Actually that is what I ended up doing :P thanks! Glad to know I have someone on the same page. I just felt like its a bit messy.